# Do we need to repeat the subject after a comma?

Tags: grammar

I read this sentence in a book:

> She ate potatoes and apples, then went outside and dug in the garden.

Don’t we need to repeat the subject after the comma?

> She ate potatoes and apples, then she went outside and dug in the garden.

Or, don’t we need to add another comma?

> She ate potatoes and apples, then went outside, and dug in the garden.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The book is correct.

This is a parallel structure, and repeated predictable elements may be omitted.  In this case, the subject "she" doesn't need to be repeated in the second clause.

The use of commas is largely irrelevant to this.

Comment: In this example the comma doesn't resolve any ambiguity, so it's not necessary (but I would put it in anyway).

Comment: @nigel222  I agree that the second comma doesn't do anything, but therefore definitely wouldn't put it in, in this case.

Comment: @MikeB I would personally, since it reads better IMO

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms I'm with Mike, "went outside and dug in the garden" sound like one action, the comma interrupts it.